# Randomly sample a subset of attributes in Weka(Java)

Tags: java, weka

I am working with the Weka API and I want to select a random subset of attributes from an Instances object. I am aware that the RandomSubset class exists which supposedly picks a random subset of attributes from the Instances object. However, this function does not seem to work. For example, from the code below, I tell the RandomSubset object to randomly select 7 attributes and use the filter class to filter my instances object, which originally has 24 attributes. I expect the output of the filter operation to give me a new instances object with just 7 randomly selected attributes but that does not happen. Instead, every time I run the code I get the SAME 12 selected attributes which tell me that RandomSubset is not random at all!

```
RandomSubset randomSubset = new RandomSubset();
randomSubset.setInputFormat(instances); // set input format
randomSubset.setNumAttributes(7); // select random number of attributes to pick
Instances sub = Filter.useFilter(instances,randomSubset); // pass randomSubset to filter object
System.out.println(sub) // contains 12 attributes instead of 7
```

How do I make this method work? Is this a bug?

Thank you,
A desperate coder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setInputFormat` call has to happen **after** all options have been set. This is where the filter will determine data structures etc based on the currently set options. Any options set after that call will simply get ignored. Think of the `setInputFormat` method as the **Apply** button in user interfaces.

Comment: Hey Fracpete, thank you for your answer. I've done what you told me to but the subset returned is not random; the randomSubset picks the same attributes each time. Btw, are you the same Fracpete, whose name I see in the weka author's list in some classes? Just curious:)

Comment: You need to change the seed value to get a different subset. The subset is random in relation to the seed, in order to get repeatable results. And yes, I have been a Weka contributor over the years.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. Aspire to be as good of a coder as you one day!